# NSTimer selector not repeating

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, nstimer, appdelegate

In my `AppDelegate` I have defined

AppDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSTimer *notificationTimer;
```

AppDelegate.m

```
@synthesize notificationTimer = _notificationTimer;

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    NSLog(@"applicationDidBecomeActive");
    self.notificationTimer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5
                                                     target:self
                                                   selector:@selector(checkForNotifications:)
                                                   userInfo:nil
                                                    repeats:YES];
    [self.notificationTimer fire];
}
```

The `checkForNotifications:` is reached once but never repeated. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:
`self.notificationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(checkForNotifications) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];`

Comment: I figured that out the moment I had posted this question. Thanks, though.